# AngularJS view not updating on ng-show inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-show

So when I mouseover the anchor tag the iconVisible variable is updated but the view doesn't even though it evaluates to true and I see that with the Inspector ? Anyone know how to solve the issue it seems so easy yet it's been bugging me for hours.

Note:What I am trying to accomplish is onmouseover a link an icon to be shown but I've stripped the unnecessary stuff.

```
angular.module('App.header', [])
.controller('HeaderController', function ($scope) {

})
.directive('menu', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        template:'<ul ng-transclude></ul>',
        scope:{

        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {

        }
    }
})
.directive('menuItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        template:'<li><a href="#" ng-transclude ng-mouseover="showIcon()"></a><img src="#" alt="" ng-show="{{iconVisible}}"/></li>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.iconVisible = false;
        },
        scope:{

        },
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            scope.showIcon = function () {
                scope.iconVisible = !scope.iconVisible;
            }
        }
    }
})

<header class="container" ng-controller="HeaderController">
<menu>
    <menu-item>Home</menu-item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour in Fiddle or Plunker?

Comment: Sure !http://jsfiddle.net/jpsk61bc/

Comment: not working... you got lotsa console errors in the fiddle

Comment: I knew it was something stupid thank you very much ! :) @harish

Comment: Sure just a sec I'm new to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace `ng-show="{{iconVisible}}"` with `ng-show="iconVisible"`

basically what you have written converts to

ng-show="true"

and given that $scope.true is undefined, ng-show does not show the element